How to run SSIS packages using Execute package activity in ADF Pipeline, When the package contains a script file that uses .exe files
we are migrating our on-prem databases to Azure Sql managed Instance and as a part of migration we wanted to run our ssis packages in ADF using Execute SSIS package activity.
I want to run the sis packages as is (with some connection changes) in ADF using execute pipeline activity.
But in our SSIS packages, we have some script tasks that are using winscp.exe files to move csv files to an sftp location.
The .exe file is located in local folder, so when executing ssis packages from onprem, the packages can take that file directly from that local path.
I tried to place .exe file in Blob storage and use the blob storage path in script file but it didn't work.
Till now we didn't find any solution to execute ssis packages in adf with minimum changes.
Do we have any solution for this?

There's a very similar question on MS Learn that has a suggestion but the OP never responded. Is this yours? Have you tried the suggestion? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2100274/how-to-run-ssis-packages-using-execute-package-act

It also appears that there is an SFTP task you can utilize in ADF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp?tabs=data-factory

I agree with @digital.aaron, you can use Execute SSIS package activity in ADF. Create new pipeline in the Activities toolbox, search for SSIS. Then drag an Execute SSIS Package activity to the pipeline designer surface. Configure it using required details as shown below:

Run your package with required details. For more information you can refer to below documents.

Use the Execute SSIS Package activity from the portal - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Learn

How to run SSIS packages using Execute package activity in ADF Pipeline, When the package contains a script file that uses .exe files - Microsoft Q&A


